# Why I am not getting the plot of reflectivity from my code?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

My code is given below. I am getting each and every plot from the start. But I am unable to get the final plot in the code shown below.

```
T[B_] := NIntegrate[(Exp[-(B/(f0[z])^2)*t] - 1)/t, {t, 0, 1}];
T1[r_, b_, B_, W_, z_] := NIntegrate[t^((r^2*(f0[z])^2)/(b^2*(f[z])^2) - 1)*(1 -Exp[-B*t]/(f0[z])^2), {t, 0, 1}];
T2[r_, b_, B_, W_, z_] := NIntegrate[(Log[t])*(1 - Exp[-B*t]/(f0[z])^2)*t^((r^2*(f0[z])^2)/(b^2*(f[z])^2) - 1), {t, 0, 1}];
T3[r_, b1_, B_, W_, z_] := NIntegrate[t^((r^2*(f0[z])^2)/((b1)^2*(fs[z])^2) - 1)*(1 - Exp[-B*t]/(f0[z])^2), {t, 0, 1}];
T4[r_, b1_, B_, W_, z_] :=NIntegrate[(Log[t])*(1 - Exp[-B*t]/(f0[z])^2)*t^((r^2*(f0[z])^2)/((b1)^2*(fs[z])^2) - 1), {t, 0, 1}];
S[wp_, L_] := 1/2*Sqrt[\[Pi]/8]*wp/L^3*Exp[-1/(2*L^2) - 3/2];
ki[wp_, L_, w_, k_, c_] := (S[wp, L]*w)/(k*(0.1)^2*c^2);
s[r_, b_, b1_, B_, W_, G_, wp_, L_, w_, k0_, k_, ks0_, c_, z_] :=NDSolve[{f0''[z] + 1/f0[z]*(f0'[z])^2 == 1/(f0[z])^3 - 
  W^2*1/f0[z]*((f0[z])^2/B*(Exp[-B/(f0[z])^2] - 1 - T[B])), f''[z] + 1/f[z]*(f'[z])^2 == 1/(4*(f0[z])^3) - 1/(4*G)* W^2*((f0[z])^2/(f[z])^2*T1[r, b, B, W, z] + (f0[z])^4/(f[z])^4*T2[r, b, B, W, z])(**Exp[2*ki[wp,L,w,k,c]*z*k0*r^2]*)(*(S[
wp,L]^2*w^2*f[z]*r^4)/(2*G^2*(0.1)^2*c^2*Exp[-2*ki[wp,L,w,k,c]*z*
k0*r^2])*), fs''[z] + 1/fs[z]*(fs'[z])^2 == (k0^2*r^4)/((ks0)^2*(b1)^4*(fs[z])^3) - (k0^2*r^4*(f0[z])^2)/(ks0^2*b1^4*(fs[z])^3)*W^2*(T3[r, b1, B, W, z] + (r^2*(f0[z])^2)/(b1^2*(fs[z])^2)*T4[r, b1, B, W, z]), f0[0] == 1, f0'[0] == 0, f[0] == 1,f'[0] == 0, fs[0] == 1, fs'[0] == 0}, {f0, f, fs}, {z, 0, 3.0}, Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> Automatic}];
a[z_] = s[24*10^(-6), 24*10^(-6), 48*10^(-6), 1.5, 2.5, 3,0.306*10^14, 0.2, 10^14, 0.59*10^7, 1.18*10^7, 0.287*10^7, 3*10^8, z] // Quiet
F0G = Evaluate[f0[z] /. a[z]]
FG = Evaluate[f[z] /. a[z]]
FSG = Evaluate[fs[z] /. a[z]]
F0 = Evaluate[f0[0.212] /. a[z]]
F = Evaluate[f[0.212] /. a[z]]
Fs = Evaluate[fs[0.212] /. a[z]]
I1[B_, r_, b1_, w0_, wp_, w_, ws_, L_, k_, k0_, ks0_, ks1_, c_, z_] :=1/4*(wp^4*ws^2)/(c^4*w0^2)*((7.6*10^-3))^2*1/((ks1)^2 - (ks0)^2 -wp^2/c^2*(1 - Exp[-(B/(F0)^2)*Exp[-((b1*Fs)/(r*F0))^2]]))^2*((Fs/(F0*F))^2)*1/(FSG)^2*Exp[-2*ki[wp, w, L, k, c]*0.212*k0*r^2 - 1];
CI1[z_] = I1[1.5, 24*10^(-6), 48*10^(-6), 1.77*10^14, 0.306*10^14, 10^14,3.54*10^14, 0.2, 1.18*10^7, 0.59*10^7, 0.287*10^7, -0.59*10^7,3*(10^8), z]
Plot[CI1[z], {z, 0, 3}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions",PlotRange -> Full]
I2[B_, r_, b_, b1_, w0_, wp_, w_, ws_, L_, k_, k0_, ks0_, ks1_, c_,z_] := 1/4*(wp^4*ws^2)/(c^4*w0^2)*((7.6*10^-3))^2*1/((ks1)^2 - (ks0)^2 - wp^2/c^2*(1 Exp[-(B/(F0)^2)*Exp[-((b1*Fs)/(r*F0))^2]]))^2*1/((FG)^2*(F0G)^2)*Exp[-((b1*FSG)/(b*FG))^2 - ((b1*FSG)/(r*F0G))^2]*Exp[-2*ki[wp, w, L, k, c]*0.212*k0*r^2];
CI2[z_] = I2[1.5, 24*10^(-6), 24*10^(-6), 48*10^(-6), 1.77*10^14, 0.306*10^14,10^14, 3.54*10^14, 0.2, 1.18*10^7, 0.59*10^7, 0.287*10^7, -0.59*10^7, 3*(10^8), z]
Plot[CI2[z], {z, 0, 3}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", PlotRange -> Full]
I3[B_, r_, b_, b1_, w0_, wp_, w_, ws_, L_, k_, k0_, ks0_, ks1_, c_, z_] := -2*(wp^4*ws^2)/(c^4*w0^2)*((7.6*10^-3))^2*1/((ks1)^2 - (ks0)^2 - wp^2/c^2*(1 - Exp[-(B/(F0)^2)*Exp[-((b1*Fs)/(r*F0))^2]]))^2*(Fs/ F0*F)*Exp[-(1/2) - 1/2*((b1*FSG)/(b*FG))^2 -1/2*((b1*FSG)/(r*F0G))^2 -ki[wp, w, L, k, c]*(0.212*k0*r^2 +z*k0*r^2)]*1/(F0G*FG*FSG)*Cos[z*r^2*(ks0 + ks1) - 0.212*k0*r^2*(ks0 + ks1)];
CI3[z_] =I3[1.5, 24*10^(-6), 24*10^(-6), 48*10^(-6), 1.77*10^14, 0.306*10^14,10^14, 3.54*10^14, 0.2, 1.18*10^7, 0.59*10^7,0.287*10^7, -0.59*10^7, 3*(10^8), z]
Plot[CI3[z], {z, 0, 3}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions",PlotRange -> Full]
```

> All is going well up to this point. But the code for reflectivity given below doesn't give me any plot.

```
R[B_, W_, r_, b_, b1_, w0_, wp_, w_, ws_, L_, k_, k0_, ks0_, ks1_, c_,z_] := I1[B, r, b, b1, w0, wp, w, ws, L, k, k0, ks0, ks1, c, z] - I2[B, r, b, b1, w0, wp, w, ws, L, k, k0, ks0, ks1, c, z] -I3[B, r, b, b1, w0, wp, w, ws, L, k, k0, ks0, ks1, c, z];
Ref[z_] = R[1.5, 2.5, 24*10^(-6), 24*10^(-6), 48*10^(-6), 1.77*10^14,0.306*10^14, 10^14, 3.54*10^14, 0.2, 1.18*10^7, 0.59*10^7,0.287*10^7,-0.59*10^7, 3*(10^8), z]
Plot[Ref[z], {z, 0, 3}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", PlotRange -> Full]
```

Comment: Could you do some basic troubleshooting on your own first? Where does the code go wrong? Try evaluating each result as you go, remove Quiet and pay attention to any warning, then evaluate the expression you are trying to plot to see if it returns real numbers. Finally, there are many Plot expressions in your code. Which one fails?

Comment: I am unable to get it on my own. Plot for R1 fails.

Answer (score 4):

You are not getting a plot because you have serious numerics problems in your code. The values of the functions `FE`, `FS` and `R1` are often far beyond the range that can be represented by machine arithmetic. You need to re-express your code so it can make use of the Wolfram Languages arbitrary precision arithmetic. I am not going to do that for you. What I will do is re-express you code so it is simpler and makes the numeric problems more obvious.

```
s[wp_, w0_, B_, n_, z_] := 
  NDSolveValue[
    {(1 - (wp^2/w0^2)*Exp[-B/(f0[z])^2*n^(2*n)*Exp[-2*n]])*f0[z]*f0''[z] == 
      4/(f0[z])^2 - 
        2*(wp^2/w0^2)*(B/(f0[z])^2)*n^(2*n)*Exp[-2*n]*
          Exp[-(B/(f0[z])^2)*n^(2*n)*Exp[-2*n]]*(3481)^2, 
      f0[0] == 1, 
    f0'[0] == 0}, 
   f0, {z, 0, .01}];
F = s[0.79*10^15, 1.77*10^15, 5, 1, z]
```

[image: interpF]

```
Plot[F[z], {z, 0, 0.01}]
```

[image: f_plot]

Every thing is OK at this point.

```
ss[wp_, w0_, B_, n_, r_, b_, c_, k_, z_] :=
  NDSolveValue[
   {fe''[z] ==
    ((fe[z]*(3481)^2)/F[z]^2)*
     ((1/(k^2*r^2*F[z]^2)*(3 + ((r*F[z])/(b*fe[z]))^4)) - 
        2*wp^2/(3*k^2*0.1^2*c^2)*B/F[z]^2*n^(2*n)*Exp[-2*n]*
          Exp[-B/F[z]^2*n^(2*n)*Exp[-2*n]]),
   fe[0] == 1, fe'[0] == 0}, fe, {z, 0, .01}]
FE = ss[0.79*10^15, 1.77*10^15, 5, 1, 10*10^-6, 10*10^-6, 3*10^8, 1.18*10^7, z];
Plot[FE[z], {z, 0, 0.01}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: fe_plot]

At this point the numerics are already unsafe.

```
sss[wp_, w0_, ws_, B_, n_, r_, b_, b1_, c_, ks0_, z_] := 
  NDSolveValue[
    {fs''[z] == 
      (fs[z]*(3481)^2)/F[z]^2*
        (1/(ks0^2*r^2*F[z]^2)*(3 + ((r*F[z])/(b1*fs[z]))^4)) - 
          ws^2/(ks0^2*c^2)*2*(wp^2/ws^2*B/F[z]^2*n^(2*n)*Exp[-2*n])*
            Exp[-B/F[z]^2*n^(2*n)*Exp[-2*n]], 
    fs[0] == 1, fs'[0] == 0}, 
   fs, {z, 0, .01}]
FS = 
  sss[0.79*10^15, 1.77*10^15, 1.24*10^15, 5, 1, 10*10^-6, 
      10*10^-6, 10*10^-6, 3*10^8, 0.287*10^7, z]
```

At this point machine arithmetic is failing big time. Mathemaica is complaining bittely about it. `FS` is unusable for furth0er computation.

Another problem with your code is that `η` needs to be defined as a function of `z`. I would rewrite it as

```
Clear[η]
η[b1_, r_, n_, z_] := (b1*FS[z])/(r*F[z]) - (2*n)^(1/2)
```

then

```
η[10*10^-6, 10*10^-6, 1, z]
```

evaluates to something usable. `R1` will also have to be rewritten.

```
R[wp_, w0_, w_, ws_, B_, n_, r_, b_, b1_, L_, c_, k_, ks0_, ks1_, n0_, N0_, z_] := 
  1/4*(wp^2/c^2)*(n0/N0)^2*(ws/w0)^2*
    1/
      (ks1^2 - ks0^2 - 
         wp^2/c^2*Exp[-B/F[z]^2((b1*FS[z])^2/(2*(r*F[z])^2))^n*
           Exp[-((b1^2*FS[z]^2)/(2*r^2*F[z]^2))]])^2*
    ((r*F[z])/(b*FE[z]))^(4*n)*
      (η[b1, r, n, z] + 2*n)^(1/2))^(8*n)/(2^(4*n)*FE[z]^2*F[z]^2)*
        Exp[-(η[b1, r, n, z] + (2*n)^(1/2))^2*((r*F[z])/(b*FE[z]))^2 - 
          (η[b1, r, n, z] + (2*n)^(1/2))^2 - 2*ki[wp, w, L, k, c]*z]
```

However, `R1` remains unusable because of the numerics problems of its constituents, which is why you can't plot it.

Comment: Do you mean that there might be something wrong with the arguments which I give to my parameters?

Comment: @amanbhatia. No, my point is that your can't use machine arithmetic to numerically solve your differential equations.